# Using has or have with a single countable noun

Tags: grammaticality

I understand the use of have and has with different pronouns, but what about the following sentence:
A successful athlete should have sufficient funds to support himself in later life.
Why don't we use the verb **has** because **athlete** is singular?

thank you

Comment: *have* is infinite here; a "conjugated" verb can't follow a modal such as *should*.

Answer (score 1):

In a chain of verbs only the first verb is finite—inflected for "tense" and for agreement with the subject. Subsequent verbs are cast in a non-finite form (infinitive or participle) determined by the preceding verb in the chain.

In your sentence the finite verb is the first, the modal verb *should*. Modal verbs do not inflect for agreement with the subject, but only for "tense", and they are always followed by a verb cast in the infinitive form—in this case, the infinitive form of *HAVE*, which is *have*.